# LaTeX: How to change size only with titlesec

Tags: fonts, titlesec

I need to change the font size of my `\subsection` headings.
Although when I use the

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.7em}{}
```

command, the font of the heading is also changed. I don't know the exact formating of the heading, so I am searching for a way to just change the size.
Can you help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Example:

```
\documentclass[DIV12,BCOR10mm,headsepline,twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.7em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Beschreibung des Steuerungsalgorithmus}
\subsection{Neuer einfahrender Ladungsträger}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the titleformat command not only changes the size but also changes the font of my subsection. It doesn't match to the section font anymore. I still want to change the size of subsection.

Edit 2:

The old one is without \titleformat. The new one is with the command, but has the wrong font!

[image: The old one is without \titleformat. The new one is with the command, but has the wrong font!]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also please elaborate a bit your question stating **exactly** what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd say “remove `\bfseries`”. However it's not really clear what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: I edited the post to clarify my problem. Better now?

Comment: For users reading this question who are using the standard LaTeX document classes instead of KOMA, the simplest way to change only the font of section headings is with the `sectsty` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using one of the koma-script document classes (scrreport).  Within the class files, the section formatting for font (which subsection relies on) is defined in the following way:

```
\newcommand*{\sectfont}{\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries}
```

When you re-define \subsection using the titlesec package with `\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.7em}{}`, you aren't telling LaTeX to use the sffamily font.  You could modify this to be `\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\sffamily\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.7em}{}`, including `\sffamily` which will give you the result you desire.

However, you can simply do the following (`\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}`), which solves your changing font problem without the need for external packages:

```
\documentclass[DIV12,BCOR10mm,headsepline,twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\addtokomafont{subsection}{\Large}

\begin{document}

\section{Beschreibung des Steuerungsalgorithmus}
\subsection{Neuer einfahrender Ladungsträger}

\end{document}
```

[image: Larger sub-section font]